# quartz spring cron trigger fire immediately

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I have a spring application that uses quartz cron trigger. I have given the following for frequency 0 0/20 * * * ?.....once every 20 min. But i want the first one to run immediately. Right now, when I start the application, it runs after 20 min. I was hoping it would run asap and then after 20 min.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need CRON expression (and Quartz at all!) to run given code every 20 minutes. Just use fixed rate (Spring built-in):

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate=20 * 60 * 1000)
```

That's it! By default first invocation happens immediately, second after 20 minutes. Since Spring 3.2 you can even say `initialDelay=10000` to run for the first time after exactly 10 seconds.

If you really want to use Quartz, check out `SimpleTrigger`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use an interval trigger (`SimpleTrigger` in Quartz can do the job).
The `CronTrigger` wants you to specify the minutes at which to run.

So your trigger schedule says: start at 0 minutes, and run every 20 minutes after that until the hour is over. Then start at 0 again.

But with the `SimpleTrigger`, you say - start now and run every 20 minutes.

Here is a tutorial on SimpleTrigger:
http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-05

Here is a tutorial on CronTrigger:
http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger