# Java Spring CronTrigger Start Immediately

Tags: java, spring, cron

I'm using a CronTrigger in Spring to schedule execution of some tasks every one hour. The first scheduling happens after one hour. Whereas I want the first scheduling to happen immediately.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myScheduler")
private ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler;

@Autowired @Lazy
private ScheduledService scheduledService; // implements Runnable

    Trigger trigger = new CronTrigger("0 0 * * * *");       
    Date date = trigger.nextExecutionTime(new SimpleTriggerContext());
    log.info("Next scheduled time for tasks - [" + date.toString() + "]");      
    scheduler.schedule(scheduledService, trigger);
```

How can I trigger the first execution immediately instead of waiting for an hour? The subsequent triggers should work in intervals of an hour.

Comment: What about this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14591276/7470253)?

Comment: As for your sample code - crontrigger will use the "LastCompletionTime" from the given context to compute the next trigger time. If that time isn't given, like in your case, then last completion time is defaulted to "Now", and "Next" time will start at least one second after the "LastCompletionTime", so after the "Now". That's how you get what you get.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Can you provide sample code for this?

Comment: There wouldn't be any sample code from me, unless you mean Spring's code. That one is on their GitHub page.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov hrat answer  code uses a constant value but I've to use expression from db, that is possible by cronJob but facing problem on startup.

Answer (score 0):

On startup you can call the task without using scheduler. After that you can left the execution to the scheduler.

For example:

```java
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 * * * *")
public void scheduleTaskUsingCronExpression() {
  // do something
}
```

But in the same class you can have something that run this on startup:

```java
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void onStartUp() {
  scheduleTaskUsingCronExpression();
}
```

Comment: How can I pass the context to the task?

Comment: What is the context? Just refactor the task to class/method with all dependencies that are needed